# Finding a NSString in an Array in a Master Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have a very interesting but difficult fun problem.

I have a string called alpha.

**alpha= @"pie"**

I have 3 arrays that were added into a master array called "ALL WORDS"

```
array 1 = [nsarray alloc]initwithobjects @"cake", @"donut"];
array 2 = [nsarray alloc]initwithobjects @"cream", @"pie"];
array 3 = [nsarray alloc]initwithobjects @"rice", @"flour"];


    allwords = [NSMutableArray array];
    [allwords addObjectsFromArray:array1];
    [allwords addObjectsFromArray:array2];
    [allwords addObjectsFromArray:array3];
```

So now I am doing a for loop like this

```
 for (int i = 0; i < [allWords count]; i++)
 {
        NSString *takestring =[allWords objectAtIndex:i];
        if ( [takestring is equal to alpha]) {
           //tell which array alpha or takestring came from????            
        }        
 }
```

My question is, how can I determine which array the pie came from. in the app people might have new words that I might not know, but i want to be able to detect where that string what array is it from?

Anybody knows how I can do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not merge array as per your description. instead you should use something like below.

```
@interface aViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *allwords;

@end

@implementation aViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.



    NSArray *array1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"cake",@"donut", nil];
    NSArray *array2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"cream", @"pie", nil];
    NSArray *array3 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"rice", @"flour", nil];
    self.allwords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:array1, array2, array3, nil];

    [self findMyArray:self.allwords];
}


- (void) findMyArray:(id)array {


    if ([array isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] || [array isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
        for (NSArray *temp in array) {
            for (NSString *str in temp) {
                if ([str isEqualToString:@"pie"]) { // define @"pie" as per your requirement
                    NSLog(@"THE ARRAY WHICH CONTAIN PIE IS %@", temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
@end
```

Using this you can simply find your array which contains specific string

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** keep track of the index of the array where we found the word, Add arrays to the Master array instead of adding the objects of each array.

```
NSString* alpha= @"pie";

NSArray  *array1 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: @"cake", @"donut", nil];
NSArray  *array2 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: @"cream", @"pie", nil];
NSArray  *array3 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: @"rice", @"flour", nil];

NSMutableArray*  allwords = [NSMutableArray array];

[allwords addObject:array1];
[allwords addObject:array2];
[allwords addObject:array3];

NSUInteger indexOfArray = -1;

for (NSArray* currentArray in allwords)
{
    for (NSString* word in currentArray)
    {
        if ([word isEqualToString:alpha])
        {
            indexOfArray = [allwords indexOfObject:currentArray];
            break; // if you don't want to loop after you find the value
        }
    }
}

// in which array I have found the word @"pie" ? ahh! I have the index of the array so

if (indexOfArray != -1) // we found the word
{
    NSArray* containerArray = [allwords objectAtIndex:indexOfArray];
    NSLog(@"%@",containerArray);
}
```